# Developing an app that recognize chords

Tags: java, c#, android

I want to develop an app that can recognize chords in songs and music,
I dont know where to start at and if there is an open source that I can use for that kind of project ...

So my question is : In java/c# - is there any openSource that I can use to proggraming with audio ?

Comment: Im a little bit confused ... why a negative vote ? :/

Comment: Please read ["How To Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: @HighCore I did and I dont understand the problem :( please tell me what I did wrong

Comment: You're question is too broad, and you ask if there are any tools, which can lead to opinion based answers.
Also looks like you don't have any starting point, which makes it even harder to answer.

Comment: @FelixAv ohhh .. I gueas you right ..

Comment: The problem is I really dont know where to start at .. but if I cant ask here .. so be it .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out signal processing libraries, read about Fourier transform and how to disassemble a signal. Then (if you still want to develop it) please come back with more focused question.